# Add Link Rel tags in a script via custom HTML tag in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to add link tags in a script and place this in the head section of the site as mentioned below:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.abc.com/" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cdn.def.com/" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://sdk-02.fhi.com/" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://sdk-02.ret.com/" />;
```

I am using Google Tag Manager and I am pushing this script through Custom HTML Tag.

```
<script>  
  (function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.innerHTML =
'<link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.abc.com/" crossorigin />'
'<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cdn.def.com/" />'
'<link rel="preconnect" href="https://sdk-02.fhi.com/" crossorigin />'
'<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://sdk-02.ret.com/" />';
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  })();

</script>
```

The issue is when I check the source code, I only see the first link added. The remaining links are not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Put Link Tags in the Script you can put it in a loop.

```
(function() {
    var a = [
    '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.abc.com/" crossorigin />',
        '<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://cdn.def.com/" />',
        '<link rel="preconnect" href="https://sdk-02.fhi.com/" crossorigin />',
        '<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://sdk-02.ret.com/" />',
    ]
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        s.innerHTML += a[i]
    }
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  })();
```

If you want add dynamicly links to the head tag you can use following code

```
(function() { 
 var linkNames = [ 
 {"url":"https://cdn.abc.com/", "rel":"preconnect", "crossorigin":true},
 {"url":"https://cdn.def.com/", "rel":"dns-prefetch", "crossorigin":false},
 {"url":"https://sdk-02.fhi.com/", "rel":"preconnect", "crossorigin":true},
 {"url":"https://sdk-02.ret.com/", "rel":"dns-prefetch", "crossorigin":false},
 ];
 for(var i = 0; i < linkNames.length; i++){
     var link = document.createElement('link'); 
     link.rel = linkNames[i].rel;
     link.href = linkNames[i].url;
     if(linkNames[i].crossorigin == true){
         link.crossOrigin = true;
     } 
     document.head.appendChild(link); 
 }

 })();
```